# How to order data by custom algorithm in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sorting, comparison, sql-order-by

I have a hierarchical table with some data in it. I've handled sorting them in a hierarchical way but there is a bug in it. I use a field named `Path` to do this. let's look at the table first:
[image]

The problem here is that mysql compares each pair of Paths as text. That if you look at those last two rows, 15 is bigger than 6 and should be swapped with the row under it.

My question is how can I compare each part of the path as numbers separated by dots?

Comment: You can develop a custom collation, which is what's used for ordering in MySQL. In that collation, you can define that `0.4.15` is larger than `0.4.6` (even though by all the rules we were taught in school - it isn't, but never mind).

Comment: it's not floating point numbers. but can you explain it in more details that how can I do this?

Comment: Provide your sample data and desired output. Your image aren't available.

Comment: @Mjh Or at least some resources

Comment: You can read about it [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/adding-collation.html) and check out [this repository](https://github.com/johnjcamilleri/utf8_maltese_ci) to see how it's installed / handled manually etc. Also, I'm not aware of any other way to implement a specific or different ordering unless a custom collation is used.

Comment: @RubahMalam The sample data is for example `0.4.6` and `0.4.15` and the data type is `TEXT`. I want mysql `ORDER BY` behave them like `0.4.15 > 0.4.15`. but it now compares them as text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say you have sample data like this :

```
id    num_text
---------------
1     0.4.3
2     0.4.2
3     0.4.15
4     0.4.23
```

This is query you need :

```
select *
from table
order by concat(
    substr(num_text,1,1),
    substr(num_text,3,1),
    lpad(substr(num_text,5,2),2,'0')
    ) asc
```

sample output :

```
id    num_text
---------------
2     0.4.2    
1     0.4.3
3     0.4.15
4     0.4.23
```

Explanation :

First, you need to make each values have the same length. For example, we convert `0.4.2 to 0402, 0.4.3 to 0403`, etc. So this query :

```
select id,
concat(
        substr(num_text,1,1),
        substr(num_text,3,1),
        lpad(substr(num_text,5,2),2,'0')
        ) as x
from table
```

the output should be :

```
id    x
--------------
1     0403
2     0402
3     0415
4     0423
```

The sample above is for the simple pattern. If you have more complicated or bigger pattern like `1.23.23.123` or `12.1.34.234`, You need more [mysql string function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html) like `LPAD`, `SUBSTR`, etc.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Can you explain your method please?

Comment: well. found a bug. this only works if the second path component is one single digit. I'm looking for a more general method. consider if the a path is like this: `0.164.182.1224`. What Now?

Comment: @HosseinMaktoobian Please see my edit. You need to provide the sample data. so we can find out what's missed from that query.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use two digits for each step of your path i.e. instead of `0.4.6` save `0.04.06` which is smaller than `0.04.15`

What I'd do on top of that is convert the path to numbers using following formula

```
0.1.7.9.10.13 -> 0.1791013
```

multiply with 10000000

```
0.1791013 * 10000000 = 1791013
```

Comment: it not a good solution. my IDs are getting bigger and bigger each time a row is inserted and it may be larger that two digits.

Comment: @HosseinMaktoobian, You can use three digits for each step i.e `0.004.006` & `0.004.015` which provides a thousand unique values for each step

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little hack:

```
SELECT INET_ATON('0.4.15')a,INET_ATON('0.4.6')b;
+--------+--------+
| a      | b      |
+--------+--------+
| 262159 | 262150 |
+--------+--------+
```